# Running rJava within JRI in JBoss

Tags: rjava, jri

I'm running an R script in Jboss (a java application server) using JRI. Within the R script I have a call to a Java class.

Therefore, this is what I have:

Java program in JBoss --> invokes JRI and runs R script --> invokes Java program.

When I attempt to run the following script in JRI:

```
s <- .jnew("java/lang/String", "Hello World")
print(s)
```

The program runs, however throws the following exception:

> 12:18:16,786 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RJavaClassLoader
>
> 12:18:16,786 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     at
>   org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.rniEval(Native Method)
>
> 12:18:16,786 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     at
>   org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine.eval(JRIEngine.java:281)
>
> 12:18:16,802 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     at
>   org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(REngine.java:102)
>
> 12:18:16,803 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)     at
>   org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(REngine.java:108)

The first time I run an rJava statement, I get the exception. From then on, it *almost* works fine, the main problem is that the environment is not stable, as I see many exceptions from time to time.

I know that is possible to run rJava from within JRI, but is it possible in an application server like Jboss instead of a plain Java object?